# Prove $\int_{0}^{1}G(t,s)ds<\frac{1}{10}$ where G(t,s) is green function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

$\int_{0}^{1}G(t,s)ds$

$G(t,s) =\begin{cases} \frac{s}{2t}(1-t^{2}), &0\leq s <t \leq 1,\\ \frac{t}{2s}(1-s^2), & 0\leq t<s\leq 1. \end{cases}$

Comment: Since $t$ is a free variable, feel free to split the integral into two integrals on intervals that are functions of $t$. e.g. $[0,t]$ and $[t,1]$, so you can then use the parametrized form of $G$ on each interval, as on the first one $s<t$ and on the second $s>t$.

Comment: Hint: since you have $0\le t,s\le1$ you can split your region into $s\in[0,t]\wedge[t,1]$ and then the function will be defined on each part of the domain